# Inserir valores e clicar no botão automaticamente no horário estabelecido

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Tenho um site com uma telinha com um formulário de login.

E minha ideia é programar o login automático para tal horário.

Por exemplo, quero ter um jeito simples de alterar no código também.

A ideia é a seguinte:

Ao dar 18:00 da noite ou outro horário que eu informar no código, o site carregar com o meu login e senha e chamar o click no submit automaticamente.

Como posso fazer isso?
Realmente vcs estão achando estranho a minha intenção e vão dizer que não é seguro etc, mas quero fazer estilo uma macro pra editar um site que já tenho usando a inspeção de elemento e aí adequar.

Mas na situação atual, quero fazer com o meu site mostrado abaixo:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Teste macro </title>
</head>
<body>
<p> Login: </p>
<input type="text" name="txtLogin"/></input>
<p> Senha: </p>
<input type="password" name="txtSenha"/>
<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="btSubmit"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Não estou conseguindo acoplar o html direto aqui na tela em que pode botar o css, html, etc, está travando no meu pc.

Qual caminho seguir pra criar essa macro?

Comment: O seu "[...] mas quero fazer estilo uma macro pra editar um site que já tenho [...]" me leva a crer que a melhor opção pra você *não é* Javascript, e sim [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/). :)

Answer (score 1):

Imagino que tu tenha que fazer um loop para testar o horário, se for o horário preenche os campos e dá um submit no form.

```
var horario = {
        hora: 18,
        minutos: 0
    },
    login = {
        email: "meu@email.com",
        senha: "secret"
    }
    input_email = document.getElementById("input_email"),
    input_senha = document.getElementById("input_senha"),
    form = document.getElementById("meu-form");


// Executa a função a cada segundo e guarda o identificados do Interval (caso seja necessário cancelar o timer)
var timer = setInterval(function(){
    var now = Date.now();

    if( now.getHours() === horario.hora && now.getMinutes() === horario.minutos) {

        clearInterval(timer);

        input_email.value = login.email;
        input_senha.value = login.senha;
        form.submit();
    }

}, 1000);
```

Comment: Dá para aumentar o `interval` para 60000 (um minuto) para não ficar processando sem necessidade